# Phantomjs on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

i have the following very simple code:

```
 var phantom = require('phantomjs');
phantom.create(function(ph){
                ph.createPage(function(page) {
                    page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
                        page.render('google.pdf', function(){
                            console.log('Page Rendered');
                            ph.exit();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```

When i run this i get an `undefined is not a function` error at the line  `phantom.create()`

I am right now sitting on a windows machine and read somewhere that i might have to use something called `dnode` my question is could this be the cause of the error or is there something in the code that might be wrong?

**Update**

I've changed `var phantom = requiere(phantomjs)` to be `var phantom = requiere(phantom)`, but now i get the error:

```
phantom stderr: 'phantomjs' is not recognised as an internal or external kommand, a program or a batchfil.
...    
AssertionError: abnormal phantomjs exit code: 1
```

Comment: I don't think phantom has a `.create` function?

Comment: i think you've followed this? https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details - which is NOT the official phantomjs module.. it's called 'phantom'

Comment: Probably worth me adding - for me I had to manually ensure phantomjs was installed AS well as phantom, modules. To do this I went into phantoms package.json, took out the phantomjs version and added it to my local package.json.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting mixed up between `phantomjs` and `phantom` node.js modules.

Your code follows the `phantom` module's pattern it looks like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom
(this is a node wrapper for phantomjs)

So, require phantom, instead of phantomjs

Be sure to have run `npm install phantom` before this

```
var phantom = require('phantom'); //not phantomjs
phantom.create(function(ph){
                ph.createPage(function(page) {
                    page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
                        page.render('google.pdf', function(){
                            console.log('Page Rendered');
                            ph.exit();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```